# How to Iterate/loop in Monit?

Tags: monit

In Monit, I have a master server and want to have Monit check the availability of all of its slaves.  The slave IP addresses and hostname increment by one, so can I create a loop in Monit, to add a check host entry for each one, without doing it manually like so:

```
check host slave1 address slave1
  # my availability tests

check host slave2 address slave2
  # my same availability tests
```

Comment: I would create the config from a template.